# Error while importing project from perforce using git p4

Tags: git, gitlab, perforce

I am trying to import a project from perforce to local using git p4.

I am following this article : https://community.perforce.com/s/article/2790

However, it fails at step number -3 as soon as I enter p4 client command and below error is generated on git bash terminal. Please help!

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `p4` is trying to create a file in a Windows temp dir, but you're in a Unix shell.  Are you able to run this command from a Windows shell, or get a version of `p4` compiled for whatever Unix-esque environment you're in?